# Анимация и движение к заданной точке при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5, анимация

Вопрос носит больше теоретический характер, наверное. Суть в чём: на сайте [lostfilm](http://www.lostfilm.tv) обновили дизайн и сделали помимо всего остального то, что привлекло моё внимание, заинтересовало - а как же это устроено, как реализовали?

Если Вы зарегистрированы на сайте, то можете отмечать прогресс просмотра серий сериалов. При нажатии на кнопку в виде глаза "просмотрено" снимок этой кнопки летит по прямой траектории с размытием и уменьшением к кнопке (которая открывает текущий раздел сайте) с таким же глазом (скриншот смотри ниже). Т.е. пользователю стразу дают понять откуда растут ноги и т.п.

[image: Пример]

Мне это показалось очень интересным и полезным. У кого какие идеи, как это реализовали и сделали?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам понадобится:

1. [`.clone()`](https://api.jquery.com/clone/), чтобы сделать копию объекта
2. [`.animate()`](https://api.jquery.com/animate/), чтобы анимировать ее
3. [`.offset()`](https://api.jquery.com/offset/), чтобы узнать координаты объектов относительно `body`
4. [`.css()`](https://api.jquery.com/css/), чтобы задать первоначальное положение объекта копии

```js
$('.source').click(function() {
//создаем копию объекта:
  var clone = $(this).clone().appendTo("body");
  
  //задаем первоначальную позицию:
  clone.css({ 
    top: $(this).offset().top,
    left: $(this).offset().left,
    position: 'absolute'
  })
  
  //анимируем к позиции цели:
  clone.animate({
    top: $('.target').offset().top,
    left: $('.target').offset().left,
    opacity: 0 //с уменьшением прозрачности
  },
  //по завершении анимации удаляем элемент:
  function() {
    $(this).remove()
  })

})
```

```css
.source {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  left: 10px;
}

.target {
  background: #ccc;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="source">source</div>
<div class="target">target</div>
```